# scan Now or Generate Now QR Code button?

Tags: java, android, generator, qr-code, barcode-scanner

So, I want a button like this in my app:

[image: Scan Now or Generate now Button]

I don't know how to add code for button in the android-studio, and I only have the scanner code. I don't know how to put 2 function in the same project. What should I do? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add a function to handle the `OnClick` event. [The Android documentation has a nice example on how to set and `OnClick` listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html):

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button_id"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/self_destruct" />
```

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
                // This should be where you add your button logic.
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm using android-studio, where should i put the code? On MainActivity or manifest? Sorry for the stupid question. I'm newbie.

Comment: The XML code belongs in the specific layout with your view. The Java code belongs in the activity that corresponds to that layout.  The application manifest is entirely unconcerned with implementing this,but it is responsible for telling the Android OS which activity IS the `MainActivity`. By default, the manifest should be fine if you didn't create an empty project.

Comment: Should i put the code on the bottom of buttton constraintlayout?

Comment: Layout and UI design is a separate topic, and you're more than welcome to post a new question here on SO.  Though, I recommend reading up on how Android uses XML for UI.  Basically you insert views into layouts, or even insert layout views into other layouts.  How you do this depends on what you want your UK to look like.

Comment: Do a little bit of learning,there are several tutorials online,get the beginner tutorials online.Unless you gain a little understanding even the most basic answers will seem complicated. Copy and pasting code you do not understand or have no idea what it does is terrible practice even though it works